# MySQL - ID not displaying correctly

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a table `author`,`shelf`,`book` The book has a foreign key of `author_id` and `shelf_id`.
In author the data is `1=Jose`, `2=William Shakespeare`.
In shelf it is `1=History`, `2=Science`.
I Added it is ID is 1,1 respectively. But when I use inner join . it displays as `Science` and `William Shakespeare`. But when I `select * from book` it displays as 1 and 1.

This is my query

```
select b.book_title, a.author_firstname, ' ' ,a.author_lastname,b.book_description,s.shelf_description,b.book_quantity 
from book b
inner join author a 
on b.book_id= a.author_id
inner join shelf s 
on b.book_id=s.shelf_id
```

Comment: Please post a more representative sample from your tables, and set it ho at http://sqlfiddle.com if possible. But glancing at this, I see you joining `book.book_id` to `author.book_id`, where your description says `book` has a FK via `author_id`, so that should be `book b join author a ON b.author_id = a.author_id`.

Comment: please write right and descriptive question for better understanding

Comment: I followed your advice and it worked correctly for me!

Comment: @WTFZane Feel free to write your own answer showing the solution you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my correct query

```
select 
    b.book_title, a.author_firstname, ' ' ,a.author_lastname) Author ,b.book_description,s.shelf_description,b.book_quantity
     from book b 
     inner join author a 
     on b.author_id= a.author_id
     inner join shelf s
     on b.shelf_id=s.shelf_id
```

The reason why it is misaligned is because the value of book_id is being equal to author_id, to which will override the display.